# How to preview a file from a generated link using Cloudfront Signed URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I have a file of with a `.pptx` file format on my Amazon S3 Bucket.

Currently I'm using AWS SDK to generate a signed URL to access that file in a browser.

This link allows me to download the file, but I want to preview the document instead of downloading it.

Is there any way to preview the document once I click on the generated link?

Comment: @Kate mentioned correct, generally S3 recognize the mime type by itself but in cases where it can't, it uses application/octet-stream which browser doesn't understand and downloads it, defining correct content-type should solve the problem. It's available in Object metadata properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preview a PPTX file in a browser the following request headers should be specified:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pptx"
```